# AWS Amplify and Cognito Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've hosted an Ionic app (Angular) on Amplify. I want to add authentication via Azure AD. I can see that Cognito has a hosted UI but I don't understand some things.

1.How can I add customize the hosted authentication page?

2.What is domain in Cognito? Is it domain for the authentication page? In which case once I get a domain for my Amplify hosted app (still in dev) how can I make sure both under same domain?

3.How to launch the login page first when I launch the URL that Amplify hosts?

I'm a beginner and I'm using the console; whats my best approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at including the [Authenticator component](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/authenticator) from [Amplify UI](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/) on your login page. This will give you the sign in, sign out, password reset and MFA flows, with simple customization allowed.

Should be quite straightforward since it sounds like you're already using Amplify for the hosting and IaC parts of your project.